# Facebook does not return to my app after accepting permissions, blank screen (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

Facebook does not validate the account after accepting the permissions, it leaves the screen blank, and I can not continue using my app.
I am using version 7.8.0 SDK (Facebook) for Unity 3D.
The version of Xcode is 8.2.1.

[Facebook was stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC0iP.jpg)

I have noticed that facebook does not send the login form, will it be a URL Schemes problem?

Comment: Is the url type correctly setup in xcode?

Comment: @JeanLuc yes I've the correctly configuration, but for one reason after accept permissions, FB.IsloggedIn is False .. I don't know why.

Comment: Try to add more details.. error code, error log..

Comment: @hB0 The problem is that xcode does not return any errors, just the debug I wrote in my code.
Probe compiling a previous project in xcode with the same settings and that if it ran well, but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
[manager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) { //in here, log your result (check whether error is nil and result) }];

Comment: In IBAction triggered when Facebook login button.

Comment: lisa:It has happened to you that when logging in with Facebook try to access
GPGSAppController?

Because apparently safari after accepting the permissions sends me to the Google code, it is rare.